# Difference between lightning-file-upload and lightning-input type="file"

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, files, lightninginput, third-party

I am using PapaParse to parse my CSV file and the function is expecting the parameter which is the File object.

When I use `lightning-input type=file` the function is working but the file collected through the `lightning-file-upload` is not working.

Just wondering if the files collected through both the inputs are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lightning-input type="file"` is meant for when you want to process a file client-side, while `lightning-file-upload` is meant for when you want to upload files to the Salesforce server as a new `ContentVersion`. `lightning-file-upload` allows you to upload files up to 2GB in size and provides a standard user interface to show the progress of the file upload. The results from a `lightning-input type="file"` are local file handles that you can use to read files, while the event from the `lightning-file-upload` provides the `contentVersionId` after the file uploads so that you can do something with the files afterwards, such as creating `ContentDocumentLink` objects.